# "TypeError: pre_get_callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lookup'" when using the get event hook in Eve

Tags: python, flask, typeerror, python-3.3, eve

I'm trying to use the pre_get event hook in Eve, but when trying to run the examples on the web page I get the following error message:

> TypeError: pre_get_callback() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'lookup'.

The complete shortdump is available at [gist.github](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/52eacb9c0d9db888bbb3)

This is my code

```
def pre_get_callback(resource, request, lookup):
    print ('A GET request on the "%s" endpoint has just been received!' % resource)
    lookup["username"] = {'$exists': True}
```

I'm using Python 3.3 and the latest version of Eve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lookup` is a 0.4 feature ([changelog](http://python-eve.org/changelog)). You're probably using v0.3 or less. If this is the case a simple

```
pip install eve --upgrade
```

will fix your problem. Eve 0.4 was released yesterday by the way.